# Microservices are getting killed automatically

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using Eureka Server for microservices, I have deployed microservices on VPS.
My server is having Centos 7. I am deploying each microservice on different screen but after some time microservice started getting killed automatically. When I check log file no error is there.

Just Eureka Server log file shows some error.

I am troubleshooting it from last 7 days but no success yet.

I have tried setting up Hikari connection timeout also make changes in various eureka configuration.

Here is my Eureka Server Log File

```
2019-05-18 01:59:34 [Eureka-EvictionTimer] INFO  c.n.e.r.AbstractInstanceRegistry - Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2019-05-18 02:00:04 [Eureka-EvictionTimer] INFO  c.n.e.r.AbstractInstanceRegistry - Running the evict task with compensationTime 49ms
2019-05-18 02:00:34 [Eureka-EvictionTimer] INFO  c.n.e.r.AbstractInstanceRegistry - Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2019-05-18 02:01:04 [Eureka-EvictionTimer] INFO  c.n.e.r.AbstractInstanceRegistry - Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2019-05-18 02:01:06 [TaskBatchingWorker-target_127.0.0.1-8] ERROR c.n.e.c.ReplicationTaskProcessor - It seems to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:193) [eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:276) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:294) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:679) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:481) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2019-05-18 02:01:08 [TaskBatchingWorker-target_127.0.0.1-16] ERROR c.n.e.c.ReplicationTaskProcessor - It seems to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:193) [eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:276) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:294) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:679) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:481) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2019-05-18 02:01:10 [TaskBatchingWorker-target_127.0.0.1-19] ERROR c.n.e.c.ReplicationTaskProcessor - It seems to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:193) [eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:276) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:294) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:679) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:481) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.7.jar!/:4.5.7]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2019-05-18 02:01:12 [TaskBatchingWorker-target_127.0.0.1-15] ERROR c.n.e.c.ReplicationTaskProcessor - It seems to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80) ~[eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:193) [eureka-core-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.11.jar!/:4.4.11]
```

Comment: I see timeout exception in your logs. check if some service is not available/accessible over the next. ERROR c.n.e.c.ReplicationTaskProcessor - It seems to be a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: My client microservice is getting killed automatically after that it shows this error. I want to know why are they getting killed.

Comment: I have seen similar issue (root cause can be different) in one of our environments. Jenkins scripts (puppet) are initiating a kill command after deployment. But if your client is app is getting killed after working for sometime, then it might be heap issues. You will not know this unless you look at the logs

Comment: please share logs from that micro service

Answer (score 0):

Often a process gets killed if it has exceeded a resource limitation.  In particular, Java applications tend to grow in memory (due to possible leaks and other factors).

So that's the first thing to check... track & see if RAM used by your Spring Boot services is increasing over time, then depending on the memory profile some mitigations can be implemented (fixing code, allocating more memory to the VPS, spreading services across more instances, recycling instances after a period of time, etc.)

Comment: I am monitoring server and will get back to you.

Comment: My issue is resolved its because of the low memory on my server. I am deploying my microservices on VPS with 4 GB of RAM and once the complete RAM is occupied the service gets killed because of out of memory.

I must have to go with the Dedicated Server with High Configuration.
Well, Thank You Guys for the help, it helps me in some way.

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer correct if it helped.